# How to find ChromeOS version on which android app running?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, google-chrome-os, android-version, androidappsonchromeos

Need to find out the ChromeOS version on which the android apps is running. Build.VERSION.RELEASE gives you the Android container version but the not the underlying ChromeOS version.

Is there a way to find it out programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: No one has an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Filed bug with chromeOS team: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=881005

Comment: To help the readers of this post & save their time, read comments 14, 16, 17 in the bug for info on where/how to extract the requested information.